# Magento Out Of Memory

Tags: magento, memory, crash, out-of-memory, out

I have changed in `php.ini` from `memory_limit = 256M` in `memory_limit = 512M` and my site just crashed.

After that I've put the old `php.ini` and still the same error, the website stopped to work. I've commented

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so"
```

and some pages started to work, but not all. On some pages I receive the message
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 35651584) (tried to allocate 7680 bytes).

From this I see that it's `35651584` and this is not `256M`, but with `phpinfo()` it's saying that it's `256M`. I don't know what it can have.

I can't access my administrator panel pages.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, the website is online.

Comment: then contact your hosting provider. You may not be allowed for more memory.

Comment: I've put back 256M how it was before, and it's not working